# rosmake -> builds something with catkin?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've created a package with a source file as always.

*roscreate-pkg testpkg roscpp*

*rosmake testpkg*

But now it created several strange catkin files in the folder build and no source file of my code was build:

catkin/            CATKIN_IGNORE   CMakeFiles/          devel/  Makefile
catkin_generated/  CMakeCache.txt  cmake_install.cmake  gtest/  test_results/

And it doesn't work :/, I've never used catkin where does it come from!?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77391/rosmake--%3E-builds-something-with-catkin!?/) by [Ros451](https://answers.ros.org/users/6340/ros451/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Delete the `CATKIN_IGNORE` file and rosmake will work again.

Update to latest catkin version to prevent the generation of that files.

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2013-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ros451](https://answers.ros.org/users/6340/ros451/) on 2013-09-09**:
Thank you very much for your reply.
No I did everything like in the tutorials or here http://mobotica.blogspot.de/2011/12/hello-ros.html